# What is supposed to be the Time Complexity of this loop

Tags: java, time-complexity

What should be the time complexity of this code?

I am thinking (n^2 -n) as the loop will run n(n-1)/2 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.println(i + "i " + j + " j");
            }
        }
```

Comment: O(n^2 -n) is asymptotically the same as O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

- i: outer loop runs n - 1 times
- j: inner loop runs n - (i + 1) times

Analyze it with a small number, say n = 10.

The outer loop will run 9 times.

The inner loop will run as follows

```
i = 0: 9 times
i = 1: 8 times
i = 2: 7 times
...
i = 8: 1 time
```

Therefore

```
n * ( n - 1) = n ^ 2 - n
```

For very large values of `n`, `n` is insignificant when compared to `n` squared.

See also [wikipedia asymtotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).